# How to send thousands of data points in a single LoRaWAN packet?

Tags: python, compression, packet, lorawan

I am currently doing a simulation, in which each second has 200k points. I want to send this in real time as much as possible with very minimal delay. The problem is sending 1 packet in LoRaWAN has delays and some packets are not sent, which is natural.

How can I send these 200k points in a single packet? For example, after 1 second I will send all data (200k points) to the network, in a packet.

BTW, I am using Python.

Comment: The entire LoRaWAN packet is 256 bytes at most, and some of that is overhead. Unless the data is highly redundant and low resolution, you're unlikely to compress it enough to fit. LoRa seems like a poor choice for something that produces this much data. I've had to look into sending few dozen channels of per-minute (or even slower) telemetry, once per day over LoRa, and even that would have been borderline workable in North America, and outright unworkable in Europe due to regulations on the ISM band.

Answer (score 1):

The use case you have is not one for LoRaWAN. It is for low data, low need applications over wide areas. 200k points (which I must assume by the name is not a single byte per unit) every second is a datatransfer of **at least** 720MB. **That is way to much.**

This is never going to work, you need to move to WiFi/Bluetooth to those kinds of transfer but your range is going to decrease dramatically.

Comment: Thank you Dan masek and @Tarick Welling for your answer. You are both correct upon checking the maximum payload size in lorawan and the delay (airtime) of the message I can't use for LoRaWAN evn I use compression techniques and lessening the sampling time of my simulation it is still impossible to do it in near realtime scenario.